# How to get/Fetch Form data in django using cloud firestore?

Tags: python, django, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, django-forms

[Form picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FE3hW.png)

ID is been selected but I'm not getting the values in the form, please check my code files. See in the picture in URL of the browser, update/id is selected, the problem is values are not fetched in the form.

**HTML**:

```
     <form id="task-form" name="myForm">
               {% csrf_token %}
               <div class="form-group">
                 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="task-building" placeholder="Building name" name="building" value="{{buildings.building}}">
            </div>
               <div class="col">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="task-postal" placeholder="Postal Code" name="postalCode" value="{{buildings.postalCode}}">
           </div>
               </div>
               </div>
               
               
                <div class="form-group">
                 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="task-town" placeholder="town" name="town" value="{{buildings.town}}">
            </div>
               <div class="col">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="task-street" placeholder="Street" name="street" value="{{buildings.street}}">
           </div>
               </div>
               </div>
               
                <div class="form-group">
                 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="task-house" placeholder="House No." name="houseNo" value="{{buildings.houseNo}}">
            </div>
               <div class="col">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="task-info"  placeholder="Additional Information" name="additionalInfo" value="{{buildings.additionalInfo}}">
           </div>
               </div>
               </div>
    
                <div class="text-center mt-3">
                <button type="submit" id="btn-task-form" class="btn btn-primary ">UPDATE</button>
                </div>
              </form>
```

**views.py**

```
def update_Building(request, id):
 docId = id;
 context = {
     'buildings': db.collection('Buildings').document(docId).get()
 }
 return render(request,"EmployeeAdmin/updateBuilding.html", context)
```

**urls.py**

```
path('update/<str:id>/',views.update_Building,name='update_Building'),
```